# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass while attempting to use a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently having the issue for when I try to use a partial inside of invoices/_form.html.erb, it goes into parts/_index.html.erb and breaks.

Inside of the parts_controller I have:

```
def _index
  @parts = Part.all
end
#unsure if this is needed
```

Inside of invoices_controller I have:`

```
def new
  @invoice = Invoice.new
  @parts = Part.all
end`
```

Inside of invoices/_form.html.erb I have:

```
  <%= render :partial => "parts/index" , :part => @parts %>
```

And inside of invoices/new.html.erb I have:

```
<h1 style="padding-left:120px">New Invoice</h1>

<%= render 'form', invoice: @invoice, part: @parts %>

<%= link_to 'Back', invoices_path, class: "btn btn-default col-md-2" %>
```

So what this code is attempting to do is display the index page of parts so the user is able to see all current parts they have in stock, and how many of that part is in stock. The parts/index page is the exact same as the the default index page for parts, but it just has a link removed.

The line of code that gives me an issue in parts/index is:

```
 <% @parts.each do |part| %>
```

And what's confusing me about that is that I should be passing it an object that has data inside of it, since it's declared in both the controller for parts, and the invoice controller. Am I missing something super simple with my syntax, or is what I'm trying to do not the right way to do it? I'm still a noob to rails, so sorry if what I'm trying to get across doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: you are sending part not @parts to your partial

Comment: @rajbir Do you mind explaining that to me? Because the way I was seeing it, :part just defined what kind of object it was expecting. Obviously that's not the case, because I just played around with it, and no matter what I change that to, it didn't affect the error that I Was getting.

Comment: I have added an answer, hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is the problem:

```
<%= render :partial => "parts/index" , :part => @parts %>
```

you are sending :part to your _index.html.erb partial while using @parts

you need to update your render call to following:

```
<%= render :partial => "parts/index" , locals: {parts: @parts}%>
```

and your loop to:

```
<% parts.each do |part| %>
```

Comment: Sorry about not replying, I had to get back to work right after I posted this. It seems that wasn't the issue, so I'm still not sure. It might be an issue with how my database is structured, since it still returns nil.

Comment: Well it appears this did fix the issue after restarting the rails server. Thank you so much man!

Answer (score 0):

you provide to `_index.html.erb` variable part but try to render @parts.
1. you don't need method _index, when your patial `_index.html.erb` render that not get variable @parts from method `_index`. I think it's wrong.
2. You need to render in `_index.html.erb` variable which it's provided from `_form`

```
<% part.each do |part_| %>
```